# Why does my nav bar disappear on small device?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to create a `header` for all pages which looks like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLrgZo).

When I resize my window the `nav bar`  disappear why?

[image]

In the above `pic` you can see `navigation link` is not there.

Could you please help me to make `nav bar` appear on every device?

Comment: You are using navbar-collapse class of Bootstrap. And that is what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bootstrap thing, just delete the **collapse** class:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
                        <ul id="menu-top" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        ...
```

to

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="navbar-collapse">
                        <ul id="menu-top" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

below is bootstrap standard nav format

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  


</body>
</html>
```